# DBPedia Live mirror setup on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, dbpedia

I am trying to set up a DBpedia Live Mirror on my personal Mac machine. Here is some technical host information about my setup:
Operating System: OS X 10.9.3
Processor  2.6 GHz Intel Core i7
Memory  16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
Database server used for hosting data for the DBpedia Live Mirror: OpenLink Virtuoso (Open-source edition)

Here's a summary of the steps I followed so far:

1. Downloaded the initial data seed from DBPedia Live as: dbpedia_2013_07_18.nt.bz2
2. Downloaded the synchronization tool from http://sourceforge.net/projects/dbpintegrator/files/.
3. Executed the virtload.sh script. Had to tweak some commands in here to be compatible with OS X.
4. Adapted the synchronization tools configuration files according to the README.txt file as follows:

   a) Set the start date in file "lastDownloadDate.dat" to the date of that dump (2013-07-18-00-000000).

   b) Set the configuration information in file "dbpedia_updates_downloader.ini", such as login credentials for Virtuoso, and GraphURI.
5. Executed "java -jar dbpintegrator-1.1.jar" on the command line.
   This script repeatedly showed the following error:

   ```
   INFO - Options file read successfully
   INFO - File : http://live.dbpedia.org/changesets/lastPublishedFile.txt has been successfully downloaded
   INFO - File : http://live.dbpedia.org/changesets/2014/06/16/13/000001.removed.nt.gz has been successfully downloaded
   WARN - File /Users/shruti/virtuoso/dbpedia-live/UpdatesDownloadFolder/000001.removed.nt.gz cannot be decompressed due to Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
   ERROR - Error:  (No such file or directory)
   INFO - File : http://live.dbpedia.org/changesets/2014/06/16/13/000001.added.nt.gz has been successfully downloaded
   WARN - File /Users/shruti/virtuoso/dbpedia-live/UpdatesDownloadFolder/000001.added.nt.gz cannot be decompressed due to Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
   ERROR - Error:  (No such file or directory)
   INFO - File : http://live.dbpedia.org/changesets/lastPublishedFile.txt has been successfully downloaded
   INFO - File : http://live.dbpedia.org/changesets/2014/06/16/13/000002.removed.nt.gz has been successfully downloaded
   INFO - File : /Users/shruti/virtuoso/dbpedia-live/UpdatesDownloadFolder/000002.removed.nt.gz decompressed successfully to /Users/shruti/virtuoso/dbpedia-live/UpdatesDownloadFolder/000002.removed.nt
   WARN - null Function executeStatement
   WARN - null Function executeStatement
   WARN - null Function executeStatement
   WARN - null Function executeStatement
   WARN - null Function executeStatement
   ...
   ```

Questions

1. Why do I repeatedly see the following error when running the Java program: "dbpintegrator-1.1.jar"? Does this mean that the triples from these files were not updated in my live mirror?

   ```
   WARN - File /Users/shruti/virtuoso/dbpedia-live/UpdatesDownloadFolder/000001.removed.nt.gz cannot be decompressed due to Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
   ERROR - Error:  (No such file or directory)
   ```
2. How can I verify that the data loaded in my mirror is up to date? Is there a SPARQL query I can use to validate this?
3. I see that the data in my live mirror is missing wikiPageId (http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageID) and wikiPageRevisionID. Why is that? Is this data missing from the DBpedia live data dumps?

Answer (score 0):

It should be fixed now.
Can you try again from here: https://github.com/dbpedia/dbpedia-live-mirror